# NewtonSoft JsonWriter.Close() - when using Response stream?

Tags: vb.net, json.net

I am new to using the NewtonSoft.Json library and have a question regarding writing JSON directly to the `Response.OutputStream` (as my understanding from reading the docs is this would be the most efficient way to return a large JSON object)...

Below is small code snippet:

```
sw = Nothing
jw = Nothing

Try    
   sw = New System.IO.StreamWriter( Response.OutputStream )
   jw = New Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextWriter( sw )

   jw.WriteStartObject()

   jw.WritePropertyName( "name" )    
   jw.WriteValue( "value" )

   jw.WriteEndObject()
Catch ex As Exception
   err_msg = ex.ToString()
Finally
   If ( jw isNot Nothing ) Then
      jw.Close()
      jw = Nothing
   End If
End Try

' Is Response.OutputStream closed as well at this point?
' Would a call to Response.Write( "anything" ) fail because the OutputStream would be closed?
```

As shown in the comments above, my questions is:

When the `JsonTextWriter.Close()` method is called, does this also close the `Response.OutputStream`?

Just want to make sure I am writing to the response stream correctly without inadvertently clobbering it should I need to do a `Response.Write()` after the fact.

Comment: Please use the [`Using` clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx) to a) write cleaner, shorter, better code and b) stop worrying about this issue.

Comment: a) "cleaner" is a matter of taste
b) I have to worry about this because as stated, Response.Write may be called after the code (in example) and if the underlying stream is closed, everything else will fail!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, by default, [`JsonTextWriter.Close()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonTextWriter_Close.htm) will call `Close` on the underlying `TextWriter`, which, if it's a `StreamWriter`, will call `Close` on the underlying stream.  However, you can set the [`CloseOutput`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonWriter_CloseOutput.htm) property on the `JsonTextWriter` to `false` to prevent this.

Comment: Just as a side note -- I tried calling Response.Write() after the Try/Catch block and it works just fine?  So it appears, even though JsonTextWriter.Close() will call Close() on the underlying stream, the underlying stream is not really closed ! -- at least, not when the stream is a Response.OutputStream.